# linux + grub.conf not exist

Tags: linux, rhel, kernel, grub

I just need to check some redhat machine version - 6

and I notice that grub.conf inst exists

how this Linux machine know with which kernel to start? ( in case grub.conf not exists )

is it safe to do a reboot to the linux in that case ?

```
08:16:41 root@test:~ # more /etc/grub.conf
/etc/grub.conf: No such file or directory

08:16:47 root@test:~ # rpm -q kernel
kernel-2.6.32-642.el6.x86_64
kernel-2.6.32-573.12.1.el6.x86_64

08:16:55 root@test:~ # ls -ltr /etc/grub.conf
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 22 Jan  4 16:46 /etc/grub.conf -> ../boot/grub/grub.conf

08:17:22 root@test:~ #
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does `cat /boot/grub/grub.conf` work?

In those days the [LILO bootloader](http://lilo.alioth.debian.org/) was also a common choice to boot a UNIX machine.

Comment: no file how to capture the latest kernel version from grub.conf

Comment: Are you sure there is grub installed (try to run `grub`)? What's the content of `/boot/grub` (`ls /boot/grub`)?